# ARC Releasing Too Soon

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I wrote a BinaryReader class in Objective-C that can extract an `NSString` from bytes created using C#'s `BinaryWriter.Write(string)`. It seems to work great, but when I call:

```
    BinaryReader *binaryReader = [[BinaryReader alloc] initWithData:dataArray];
    NSString *strName = [binaryReader readString];
    // strName is not nil, but the value is no longer correct (seems to have been erased)
```

I stepped into the readString method, and everything looks great (the string is correct) up until the method returns (I think ARC is kicking in).

Why would this be happening?

Here's my readString method:

```
-(NSString *)readString
{
    NSUInteger bytesCount = (NSUInteger)[self read7BitEncodedInt];
    const void *byteData = [_data bytes] + _dataIndex;

    NSString *returnValue =
        [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:byteData length:bytesCount encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    _dataIndex += bytesCount;
    return returnValue;
}
```

The `returnValue` contains the proper string right before the method returns.

By request, here's my init function for BinaryReader.

```
-(id)initWithData:(NSData *)theData
{
    self=[super init];
    if(self != nil)
    {
        _dataIndex = 0;
        _data = theData;
    }
    return self;
}
```

and the relevant part of header

```
@interface BinaryReader : NSObject
{
    @private
    NSData *_data;
    int _dataIndex;
}
```

Comment: Can you show how readString looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the result is actually broken? The code you posted seems fine and there should be no ownership/memory issues when compiled with ARC.

Lately there have been issues reported with lldb (the debugger) not showing correct values in some cases. Try to log the result using `NSLog`.

Comment: YOU'RE RIGHT! I put in an `NSLog(strName);` after the call to `readString` and the value I saw in the log was correct. Thank you soo much! And GRRRR XCODE SOO BUSTED! Don't even got me started; million problems with it, and I have to encounter them all!

You wouldn't happen to also know how to get unit tests to stop throwing a warning that they did not finish, would you? Found about 5 stack overflow posts on it, but no solutions. :)

Comment: "I put in an NSLog(strName); [...]" Don't ever do this! It's broken and dangerous. Log strings using `NSLog(@"%@", strName);`

Comment: Yah, the warning message it gave me reminded me not to do it too. That line is no longer there, but if I were to re-add it, I'd use `NSLog(@"%@", strName);`. Wish I could give you more than one upvote. :)

Answer (score 0):

ARC should not release the object so soon, so your error might be inside the readString itself.

Comment: The value of `returnValue` is correct right before the method actually returns. The string goes from something like `0x5352525@"HelloWorld"` to just `0x5352525 0 key/value pairs`.

Answer (score -2):

Put your binaryReader as a property with the strong attribute, it may solve your problem.

```
@propert(nonatomic, strong) BinaryReader* binaryReader;
```

It tell to the compil to not release the object.

Comment: The `BinaryReader` object seems to remain valid, because if I call `readString` again (to grab the next string) and step into the method, it extracts is correctly, it just can't seem to be able to return the string without it being erased.

Comment: Automatic variables are `__strong` by default.